# How do I add a span to asp:TemplateColumn th?

Tags: .net, asp.net, datagrid

The Code:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources:index, IndexSearch_Header_Product %>"
HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"> 

    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="productLink" /> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

I changed the header text to `HeaderText="<span><%$ Resources:index, IndexSearch_Header_Product %></span>"` and it gave me the span but just printed "<%$ Resources:index, IndexSearch_Header_Product %>" in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
HeaderText="<%$ Resources:index, IndexSearch_Header_Product %>"
```

And add a `<HeaderTemplate>` like so:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <span><asp:Literal id="header" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:index, IndexSearch_Header_Product %>" /></span>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="productLink" /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I add an ID to this <td>? (not this span). For CSS

Answer (score 0):

There should be a HeaderTemplate, which you can use to render the resource...  You can use a Label and embed in the label text the resource string.

HTH.

Comment: "There should be a HeaderTemplate"; Where? In the aspx.cs? Don't know what you mean by the last bit

Comment: As in @mdmullinax post, in markup, similar to ItemTemplate, there should be a HeaderTemplate property...